# Reset title to metadata value after changing it dynamically

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, app-router

In my Next.js project, I change the page title dynamically in reaction to an event:

```
if (unread_count === 0) {
  document.title = "Flow Chat";
} else {
  document.title = `Flow Chat - ${unread_count} unread messages`;
}
```

The default title of the page is set in the `layout.tsx`:

```
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Flow Chat",
  description: [...],
};
```

Is it possible to reset the page title to the one set in `metadata` instead of hardcoding the text a second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious thing here is to simply import the defined `metadata` from your `layout.tsx` into the file you want to use it, however this is not possible if you want to use it in a `"use client"` file.

You can solve this by creating some kind of separate file where you declare your metadata, say **constants/metadata**.

```js
export const defaultMetadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Flow Chat",
  description: [...],
};
```

This you can import into the `layout.tsx`

```js
import { defaultMetadata } from "@/constants/metadata";

export const metadata = defaultMetadata;
```

and your `client.tsx`

```js
"use client"

import { defaultMetadata } from "@/constants/metadata";

if (unread_count === 0) {
  document.title = defaultMetadata.title;
} else {
  document.title = `Flow Chat - ${unread_count} unread messages`;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to make the most sense!